# Saving the arguments of a function each time it is called, using a decorator defined in a parent class

Tags: python, python-decorators, code-inspection

I have a series of parent-children classes A(), B(A),... possibly in different modules. A user will import one of these classes and define its own child class Z(X) deriving either from X = A, B,.... Then he will initialize his instance with an initialize method defined in the parent class X, or in his overridden initialize in Z. I want the initialize function to save its arguments each time it is called and I have prepared in A() a save_last_arginfo() function that could be called automatically by a decorator of initialize.

I give an example that works with save_last_arginfo being explicitly called from Z.initialize(). How to replace this call by the decorator defined in A? I am not sure

- how to code this decorator
- how to treat self in the decorator definition and @decorator syntax
- how to refer to the decorator (should I specify A.decorator or is the filiation enough?)
- whether the relevant frame level for determining the arguments will change with the decorator compared to the direct call, in getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0]

```
   import inspect
   import functools

   class A():
        
      lastargsinfo = None
    
      #@decorator   
      def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
         pass

      def save_last_arginfo(self):
         args1, varargs1, varkw1, defaults1, = inspect.getfullargspec(self.initialize)[0:4]
         frame = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][0]       # will this work when using the decorator
         args2, varargs2, keywords2, locals2 = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
         self.lastarginfo = [args1, defaults1,  locals2] # I'll do a dictionary with args and kwargs later
    
      def decorator(self):                  # is this syntax correct?
         @functools.wraps(self.func)
         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.save_last_arginfo()
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
         return wrapper

        
   class B(A):
      #@decorator   
      def initialize(self, a, b=1):
         pass
        
   class Z(B):
      #@decorator                       # how to correct this syntax? A.decorator? what to do with self?
      def initialize(self, a, b=1, c=2, **kwargs):
         self.save_last_arginfo()       # how to remove this line and use the decorator instead
         return (a+b)*c


   myZ = Z()
   myZ.initialize(0,b=3, c=8, d=12)
   print(myZ.lastarginfo)
   # returns [['self', 'a', 'b', 'c'], (1, 2), {'self': <Z object at 0x000001BBBF135340>, 'a': 0, 'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'kwargs': {'d': 12}}]
```

Comment: You should try and focus your questions; you are asking a lot of different things here. That being said, is there a good reason why you have `initialize` instead of the normal `__init__`? Also, are you married to the decorator approach already or are you open to other solutions; is your actual goal just the ability to save the arguments passed to the init method for later?

Comment: My focus is storing in a Z attributes the arguments of initialize at each initialize calls. initialize comes here in addition to _init_ (not shown in this example). The A, B, ..., Z classes are intrument drivers and initialize starts a dialog with the instrument. Classes A, B, C are programmed by me, whereas Z and its possibly overriden initialize is programmed by different users. I find it convenient to ask these users to simply decorate their new initialize by "atB.decorator \n class Z(B):". I answer to my own question with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to reformulate Daniil answers, keeping it simple for me, and closer to my goals, in order to check whether I have understood and to continue the discussion.

```
import inspect
import functools

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_call_info = []
       
    def save_last_call(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.last_call_info  = [inspect.signature(func), args, kwargs]
            return result
        return wrapper
    
    @save_last_call
    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
        
    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        setattr(cls, "initialize", cls.save_last_call(cls.initialize))
    
class B(A):
    def initialize(self, a, x=5, y=8):
        # Do something here
        pass

class Z(B):
    def initialize(self, a, b, x=5, y=8):
        # Do something here
        pass
        
myZ = Z()
myZ.initialize(1,2,x=4)
print(myZ.last_call_info)
```

outputs:
[<Signature (self, a, b, x=5, y=8)>, (1, 2), {'x': 4}]

Note that in the wrapper, I have to call func BEFORE storing its arguments to avoid a bug occuring when the last programmer who overrides initialize in Z choose to reuse X.initialise (by calling super for instance), so that save_last_call is called twice for two different initialize with different arguments. Example:

```
class Z(B):
   def initialize(self, a, b, x=5, y=9):
      super().initialize(a, x=x ,y=y)
      self.b = b
   
myZ = Z()
myZ.initialize(1,2,x=4)
print(myZ.last_call_info )
```

outputs now the correct result
[<Signature (self, a, b, x=5, y=9)>, (1, 2), {'x': 4}]

Answer (score 2):

You could write a decorator for `initialize`, but this would mean that users who wish to override `initialize` in their subclass **must** also use the decorator. If they don't, their implementation will not call your `save_last_arginfo` method.

If you want to get around this problem, you can define [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) on your base class and perform the decoration for `initialize` there. That way the decorator is applied to each subclass' `initialize` method and users don't even need to know about the existence of your decorator.

To simplify a bit, I am just going to show how to store the `args` and `kwargs` for the last `initialize` call, and not do extensive introspection. Here is a simplified example of what you described with my suggested approach:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import Concatenate, ParamSpec, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")


class A:
    last_args: tuple[object, ...]
    last_kwargs: dict[str, object]

    @staticmethod
    def save_last_method_call(
        unbound_method: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]
    ) -> Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]:
        @wraps(unbound_method)
        def wrapper(self: T, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            self.last_args = args
            self.last_kwargs = kwargs
            return unbound_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @classmethod
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **_kwargs: object) -> None:
        setattr(cls, "initialize", cls.save_last_method_call(cls.initialize))

    def initialize(self, a: int, b: int = 1) -> None:
        pass
```

On the user's side, we could have this:

```py
class Z(A):
    def initialize(self, a: int, b: int = 1, c: int = 2, **kwargs: int) -> None:
        pass


def main() -> None:
    z = Z()
    z.initialize(0, b=3, c=8, d=12)
    args = z.last_args
    kwargs = z.last_kwargs
    print(f"initialize({args=}, {kwargs=})")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
initialize(args=(0,), kwargs={'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'd': 12})
```

---

I think it makes sense to define the decorator as a `staticmethod` because on the one hand the class itself is not really needed, but on the other hand it relies on `self` inside the wrapper to be an instance of `A`. Therefore the method is intimately related to the `A` base class.

One advantage of this setup is that you can very easily apply this decorator to any other method of any subclass of `A` or even to all of them, if you want to. If you do that inside `__init_subclass__`, it guarantees the decoration of those methods for every subclass. (Unless of course a user overrides `__init_subclass__` himself and does not call the parent's method.)

What exactly you want to do inside `save_last_method_call` is ultimately up to you. This just demonstrates the concept of applying the decorator automatically. If you want to do more inspection there, I don't really see an issue with that.

---

In my code I used type annotations, which pass `mypy --strict` cecks. But for [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) and [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) to be supported, you need Python `3.10+`. If you are on an earlier version, it might be enough to simply change the `typing` imports to this:

```py
...
from typing import TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec
```

Comment: Thank you very much. We were answering at the same time. I delete my concommitent post and study yours

Comment: There's no need to use `setattr` if you're hard-coding the method name in `__init_subclass__`. You can just write `cls.initialize = cls.save_last_method_call(cls.initialize)`.

Comment: OK I have edited my last answer. accordingly

Comment: @Blckknght Have you tried running `mypy` over it? If you did, you may have noticed that direct assignment causes an error that has been [well documented](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2427) for years and the current best practice is to use `setattr`. Of course it makes no difference from the perspective of the interpreter.

Comment: @Daniil 1)What is the difference between what you proposed and my last answer? 2) why do you think save_last_call should be static? 3) Does it cause this complicated save_last_method_call(unbound_method: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]) -> Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R] that I don't understand?

Comment: @Daniil When I make save_last_call static, I get an error when decorating initialize with it in A...